# How to display Wordpress Posts for each day in a table in descending order (Recent Post First)?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to Group each post in a date-wise order inside a table.

[Please check the attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqjio.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
// where post_date > today
$where .= " AND post_date >= '" . date('Y-m-d') . "'"; 
return $where;
```

}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

Use this code